# Can I add custom styling to a leaflet layer panel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, leaflet

I am using leaflet.js to create a simple map of NYC. The "parent layers" are the boroughs and the "children" are the neighborhoods.

I want to be able to expand and collapse the parents to show the child layers. I also want to indent the child layers.
[Current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsZ2j.jpg)
[example desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzykN.png) - I drew on a drop down & changed some CSS in the dom itself. Below is the code I am working with:

```
        let nyc = new L.LatLng(40.75042, -73.98928);
        let map = L.map('map').setView(nyc, 10);
        let esriUrl = 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/{style}/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}';
        // Specify the Esri style name
        let styleName = 'World_Topo_Map';
        let legend;

        // Create the tile layer using the Esri URL
        L.tileLayer(esriUrl, {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri',
            style: styleName
        }).addTo(map);

        let boroughUrl = 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/7t3b-ywvw.json';
        let neighborhoodUrl = 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/q2z5-ai38.json';

        addBoroughsToMap = (boroughGeom) => {
            boroughGeom.features.forEach(feature => {
                let layer = L.geoJson(feature.the_geom);
                layer.addTo(map);

            })
        }

        let finalData = {};

        parseNeighborhoodData = (neighborhoodData) => {
            let parsedHoods = {};

            neighborhoodData.features.forEach(feature => {
                let boroName = feature.boro_name;
                let neighborhoodName = feature.ntaname;
                let geometry = feature.the_geom;
                let layer = L.geoJson(geometry)
                // create the boro key for each boro
                // add properties to each boro
                if (!parsedHoods[boroName]) {
                    parsedHoods[boroName] = {
                        name: boroName,
                        neighborhoods: [],
                        layerGroup: L.featureGroup(),
                        
                    }

                }

                // Add a click event listener to each borough layer
                parsedHoods[boroName].layerGroup.on('click', function () {
                    // Toggle all neighborhood layers when a borough layer is clicked
                    parsedHoods[boroName].neighborhoods.forEach(neighborhood => {
                        neighborhood.layer.eachLayer(neighborhoodLayer => {
                            neighborhoodLayer.setStyle({ opacity: neighborhoodLayer.options.opacity ? 0 : 1 });
                        });
                    });
                });

                // add elements to neighborhoods properties
                parsedHoods[boroName].neighborhoods.push(
                    {
                        boroName: boroName,
                        neighborhoodName: neighborhoodName,
                        geometry: geometry,
                        layer: layer
                    }
                );

                parsedHoods[boroName].layerGroup.addLayer(layer); // Add neighborhood layers to each boro's layer group
            })
            finalData = parsedHoods;
            return parsedHoods;
        }
        let boroughLayerControl = {};

        createLegend = (neighborhoodData) => {
            let controlLayers = {};

            // let boroughLayerControl = {};

            let groupA;

            Object.values(neighborhoodData).forEach(boro => {
                let layerName = boro.name;
                // add each boro layer group to the map (aka entire manhattan layer would be added here...)
                let groupLayer = boro.layerGroup;
                // groupLayer.addTo(map);
                controlLayers[layerName] = groupLayer;
                // add each borough layer group to the nested control
                boroughLayerControl[layerName] = groupLayer;

                //add each neighborhood layer to the map (aka chelsea layer would be added here...)
                boro.neighborhoods.forEach(neighborhood => {
                    let neighborhoodName = neighborhood.neighborhoodName;
                    let neighborhoodLayer = neighborhood.layer;
                    controlLayers[neighborhoodName] = neighborhoodLayer;
                    boroughLayerControl[layerName + " - " + neighborhoodName] = neighborhoodLayer;
                });


            })


            // L.Control.CustomLayers(null, controlLayers).addTo(map);
            legend = L.control.layers(boroughLayerControl);
            legend.options.collapsed = false
            legend.addTo(map);


        }

        // let boroughGeom;
        let neighborhoodData;

        fetch(neighborhoodUrl)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }
                else {
                    throw new Error('Error: Failed to retrieve data.')
                }
            })
            .then(geoJsonData => {
                neighborhoodData = turf.featureCollection(geoJsonData);
                // addBoroughsToMap(neighborhoodData);
                neighborhoodData = parseNeighborhoodData(neighborhoodData);
                createLegend(neighborhoodData);
            })
```

I have tried using both layerGroups and FeatureGroups but can't find any solid documentation for changing leaflet.js dom attributes.